# Android path not getting

Tags: android

When I am dealing with an iPhone application, I know where the sandbox of the application is stored and when I save something  I can easily access the document directory of my application.

But, in android, I don't know what is the similar thing to it, so can anybody let me know where this file will be stored and how can I can get the access to it?

Answer (score 0):

it'll be stored in your workspace under the folder with projects name

Answer (score 0):

You can read some general information about resources in android here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

To access internal storage of the deviace:

For reading:

```
InputStream is = getContext().openFileInput(filename);
```

For saving:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
    out.writeObject(survey);
    out.close();
```

If you use eclipse you can browse files using DDMS perspective (Window->OpenPerspective->Other->DDMS).